# Django interpreting dict values ambiguously

Tags: python, django, unicode

Python interpreting QueryDict ambiguously. When I print `request.POST` values, I see the values I'm expecting i.e `1 and 3`. However when I print the list, I see only `3` being printed.

```
(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'subjob_ids[]': [u' 1 ', u' 3 '], u'updated': [u''], u'created': [u''], u'job_name': [u'Job11'], u'jobtype_id': [u'1'], u'no_of_subjobs': [u'2'], u'operation': [u'addjobwithexistingsubjobs'], u'id': [u'-1']}>

(Pdb) request.POST['subjob_ids[]']
u' 3 '
```

Checked if this is problem with `u`unicode, but it's not. When I convert unicode to `str` , I see only `3`.

```
(Pdb) str(request.POST['subjob_ids[]'])
' 3 '
```

So is there a problem with the data present in QueryDict?

I tried taking this value into python interpreter instead of pdb, it just works perfectly.

```
>>> dict = {u'subjob_ids[]': [u' 1 ', u' 3 '], u'updated': [u''], u'created': [u''], u'job_name': [u'Job11'], u'jobtype_id': [u'1'], u'no_of_subjobs': [u'2'], u'operation': [u'addjobwithexistingsubjobs'], u'id': [u'-1']}
>>> dict
{u'subjob_ids[]': [u' 1 ', u' 3 '], u'jobtype_id': [u'1'], u'updated': [u''], u'no_of_subjobs': [u'2'], u'created': [u''], u'operation': [u'addjobwithexistingsubjobs'], u'job_name': [u'Job11'], u'id': [u'-1']}

>>> dict['subjob_ids[]']
[u' 1 ', u' 3 ']

>>> dict['subjob_ids[]'][0]
u' 1 '

>>> dict['subjob_ids[]'][1]
u' 3 '
```

Is there something wrong with how django is treating the data?

Comment: It's a [MultiValueDict](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py#L48). And no issue, it's just not intended for displaying this way.

Comment: Read the docs on [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), particularly on the `__getitem__()` and `getlist()` methods.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the source, it did solve the problem :)